# Error trying to store current date and time

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am trying to store the current date and time in a column of a table in my database, but I have not been successful. I do not understand why I cannot save this column in my database table.

My server date time format is: 05/02/2022 09:38 A.M

PS: I can't change the date and time format to my server

I'm running this code:

```cs
inventory.created_date = DateTime.Now;
```

This is the first error I get:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

[image]

As I understand the first error is due to an incorrect format

That's why I try to format it in a way that SQL Server can understand.

So I try to convert the obtained date to a `string`, give it a format and then convert it back to type `DateTime`

```cs
var x = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss");
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(x);
inventory.created_date = date;
```

And this is the second error I get:

> System.FormatException: String '05022022 09:45:39' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>
> at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
> at API.Controllers.InventoryController.Create(Inventory inventory) in C:\WebApp\backend\API\Controllers\InventoryControllers.cs:line 38
> at lambda_method6(Closure , Object )

Complete code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("create/")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([FromBody] Inventory inventory)
{
    var x = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var date = Convert.ToDateTime(x);
    inventory.created_date = date;
    db.Add(inventory);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Ok("saved!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**Updated**

Api Fluent

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Requirement> Requirements { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        #region Inventory
        // Table name
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .ToTable("Inventories");
        // ID
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .HasKey(i => i.inventory_id);
        // Name
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .Property(i => i.name)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(100)")
            .HasMaxLength(100);
        // Location
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .Property(i => i.location)
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(100)")
            .HasMaxLength(100);
        // Status
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .Property(i => i.status)
            .IsRequired(true)
            .HasColumnType("tinyint")
            .HasMaxLength(255)
            .HasDefaultValue(1);
        // Create Date
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .Property(i => i.created_date)
            .IsRequired(true)
            .HasColumnType("smalldatetime");

        // Update Date
        modelBuilder.Entity<Inventory>()
            .Property(i => i.modified_date)
            .IsRequired(true)
            .HasColumnType("smalldatetime");

        // ID
        modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
            .HasKey(i => i.asset_id);
        // Table name
        modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
            .HasOne(i => i.Inventory)
            .WithMany(a => a.Assets);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Asset>()
            .ToTable("Assets");
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: `var x = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss"); var date = Convert.ToDateTime(x);` - ****why****? `DateTime` has no format, so you can't format the date by doing this, and this is probably where things are going wrong. Just assign `inventory.created_date = DateTime.Now;` and call it a day.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: `DateTime` stores one value: a `long` value called `Ticks`. Every other property is calculated from this. The human-readable date you see in the debugger is a result of converting the `DateTime` to a `string`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar 
Let's see if I understood you, SQL and C# handle this type of data as a long? Does that mean I don't have to convert the obtained date to a string?

if I just set `inventory.created_date = DateTime.Now;` I get error #1
`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

Comment: Essentially yes, that's more-or-less correct. What is the type of `created_date` in C#, and what is the column type in SQL Server?

Comment: `MMddyyyy` is certainly not a format that SQL Server will always understand. See the "Regional date formats" section of [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates) and use one of the safe formats prescribed there.

Comment: It should make no difference but SqlServer does not handle DateTimes as ticks. Its a double since a predefined startdate. Where complete numbers represent a complete  day and the fractions a partial day. But thats background detail. EF should know those details and attaching a DateTime object to your model should work.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar post updated column type ` .HasColumnType("smalldatetime");`

Comment: Did you forget to set the required modified_date?

Comment: @Ralf That certainly seems to be the most likely explanation.

Comment: @Ralf  omg, I focused so much on the error, that I stopped thinking, you are right, I needed to define the required field `modified_date` now if you manage to do the insert in the database! I no longer have to do those conversions! Thank you!!!

Comment: Do I have to delete this post?
or posted an answer to accept it

Comment: Nah. You just have to take our unquestioned advices ;) Don't store local date use Utc date (so UtcNow instead Now). Local if something different for different potential users and Utc as the u suggests is universal. Think hard about using specific models for your endpoints different then the persisted models and map between those. You already have things in the model a user should have no access to when creating something (like the two dates or the id).

Comment: @Ralf Thanks for the advice, if I'm going to define the mapping of the <Inventory> entity,
A question to see if I understand.
`DateTime.Now` gets the date from the server but `DateTime.UtcNow;` gets the date from the client pc that is making the request?

I am right?

Comment: No. Local just doesn't define a timezone. Its just mean the current one. So after storing it in the database you don't now what current was on the server at the time that the date has been created.  Its the current one and current can change but Utc can't.  If someone from the US and someone from Germany is calling your presumably existing GET endpoint for Inventories they will see the same date but it will have a different meaning to them. And as you don't now what timezone was used when the Inventory has been created you can't correct it.

Comment: The approach to format the datetime in a format that SQL Server understands is the right one. The format "MMddyyyy HH:mm:ss" is not suitable.  Use "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss" instead.

Comment: @Gert that is incorrect. It implies you use strings concatenation to build your SQL queries rather than using prepared statements and parameters (yay! SQL injection and reduced performance due to no shared execution plans!). Entity Framework and indeed SqlCommand are both perfectly capable of sending a `DateTime` value to the database on a binary level without resorting to sending them as text.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I think you misinterpreted the point, it was not "you should always use strings to pass dates," it was, "when you _do_ need to pass strings (because you don't always have strong typing etc), you shouldn't use a garbage format that SQL Server might misinterpret." Advice that goes beyond EF, SqlCommand, or any client language whatsoever.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Perhaps I did. I read the first sentence as suggesting that formatting the date as a string as the right approach. I guess it maybe didn't mean that.